# Find a vector along the vector < 3,6 > of length 7

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

I know I'm supposed to use the dot product, but I have no idea how to set it up, considering our professor didn't cover THIS type of problem. [I decided to draw it out to start off.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XV0fe.jpg)

What formula should I be using in this situation? Thanks so much

Comment: Can you at least find the length of the given vector?

Comment: I did! 3sqrt(5). Sorry, I did it after that screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Well, the vector $<3,6>$ is in the direction $\theta=\tan^{-1}(\frac{6}{3})$.  So you can define a vector in that direction with magnitude 7.  If you want the components of that new vector, it could be 
$$
<7\cos(\theta),7\sin(\theta)>
$$
Or if you'd like, the unit vector in the direction $<3,6>$ is given by 
$$
\hat{v}=\frac{<3,6>}{\|<3,6>\|}
$$
so you could define your vector as 
$$
7\frac{<3,6>}{\|<3,6>\|}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Can you compute the length of $\lt 3,6\gt$?  Now just multiply by a scalar that makes the length $7$

Comment: I used the Pythagorean theorem, and the hypotenuse ended up being 3sqrt(5). Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes. What do you multiply that by to get $7$?

Comment: It 's 7/3sqrt(5) right?

Answer (score 0):

The question is asking you to find a vector, pointing in the same direction as $\langle 3, 6\rangle$, but has length $7$. The picture you made doesn't accurately represent the situation, as both vectors need to be parallel.

To find this, you simply need to scale $\langle 3, 6 \rangle$ by a positive scalar that makes the length $7$. Such a scalar is simply
$$\frac{7}{\|\langle 3, 6 \rangle\|} = \frac{7}{\sqrt{3^2 + 6^2}} = \frac{7}{3\sqrt{5}}.$$